# Code from a previous git commit not working?

Tags: git

Using git on a local repository where I am the only user, I want to go temporarily go back to a previous commit where my code was running. However, when I set HEAD back to this point, and try to run the code, it won't even compile. I labeled the commits so I know I am at a point that should be working, is there something I am doing wrong?

Edit: I think my question is ambiguous, so I will simplify:
The point of what I am asking is not about code, it is about git itself. If I commit working code, make more commits afterwards, and try to access a previous commit where the code was working, shouldn't that code work since it did indeed work at the point at which I committed it?

Comment: How can we possibly know why some revision of your code isn't compiling? You haven't shown us the code or the error messages you're getting.

Comment: The issue is that the code was working when I committed, but does not work when I try to access said commit. My question is: when I commit working code, make more commits afterwards, and go back to access the working commit, shouldn't it still be working? I'm interested in why git does this, not in the specific code itself.

Comment: In general, Git doesn't break your code. You'll have to show some examples of code that works differently from how you expect and the exact Git commands that you're using.

Comment: Unless you version all your build tools in your Git repository then you have no guarantees

Answer (score 1):

Although you've gone back to a previous commit, you may still have **changes to your Working Copy** that are preventing the code from running as it did then. Ensure that no local, uncommitted changes have been made on top of that past commit.

Use a Hard Reset to return to an SHA and additionally discard any local changes.

`git reset --hard c73492bc`

If the committed code was truly working when that commit was made, reverting to that commit now should still result in working code.

Comment: To add, it works both ways of course. If there were unstaged local changes when the old commit was made, then the old commit does not reflect the working state.

Comment: You may want to usw `git stash` instead oft resetting hard to prevent losing your local changes for good.

Answer (score 1):

When you check out the previous commit, what you check out is bit-for-bit identical with what you committed.

Whatever about the build has changed since building that commit worked has, by mathematical and cryptographic guarantee, nothing to do with what you asked git to remember.  Something else changed -- you overlooked source when committing, you didn't commit everything.